# Firebase Cloud Messaging - iOS - notregistered or cannot subscribe to topic

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

After struggling with Firebase Cloud Messaging for a few hours I figured out the problem and want to post here since I couldn't find an answer before.

My problem was: I was working with Firebase Cloud Messaging and having a lot of trouble subscribing to topics and receiving messages. I would often get "notregistered" errors when trying to send a message directly to the device and Failed to subscribe to topic Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=0 "(null)" when subscribing to topics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, the answer was very simple. The app had initially been installed through TestFlight and then I had installed OVER that from XCode. I simply uninstalled the app from the device completely, and then installed through XCode and all was well again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for answering, even though you have no problem anymore.

From what I know, that kind of error usually caused by the app has not fully configured to FCM.

I can not immediately subscribe or get the token right after the `FirebaseApp.configure()` was called, it need some time. So, wait for a second, literally one second, solved the issue.

```
sleep(1)
```

Just mindful, about which thread you are pausing to.

After that, every time the app send request to backend, the token is ready, and successfully subscribed to desired topic.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked to resolve the `NotRegistered` error:

1. open up my project in xCode
2. with the `Project navigator` click on my project name
3. Click the `Capabilities` tab
4. Turn on **Push Notifications**

[This comment](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/77#issuecomment-249433845) from GitHub helped me to resolve this. Apparently some times/versions of xCode doesn't listen to the entitlements you have specified in your provisioning profile, so you *also* have to manually set it from within xCode.